# Android: Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, final

I know this question has been asked several times before, but I upon reading many answers, I haven't found something which suits me. First, please look at the following code, which is supposed to open an AlertDialog once an image is clicked (this works perfectly). The AlertDialog hosts an EditText field - this is where the problem arises:

```
    ImageView scissorsImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.scissorsImage);
    scissorsImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            alert.setTitle("Apply a Coupon");
            alert.setMessage("Enter the coupon amount (i.e. 25 for $25)");

            // Set an EditText view to get user input 
            final EditText couponAmount = new EditText(context);
            alert.setView(couponAmount);

            couponAmount.setText(couponAmountString);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String couponAmountString = couponAmount.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println(couponAmountString);
                }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                }
            });

            alert.show();
        }

    });
```

Now, this bit of code is inside my `onCreate` method, and the variable `couponAmountString` is outside the `onCreate` method. So the code executes just fine, the only problem is that the line `couponAmount.setText(couponAmountString);` does not work as I want it to.

What I am trying to do with it is that when the user puts a value in the dialog box, and closes it by pressing OK, the value gets stored in `couponAmountString` - so far so good. When the user touches the image again to re-open the dialog box, I am *trying* to have the EditText field pre-set with the last value they entered, hence `couponAmount.setText(couponAmountString);`. But this isn't working, because I have to declare the EditText field as `final`. Which is why I get the error `Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method` when I click on the image the second time.

So is there any way I can accomplish what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Silly, silly me. It turns out that I was re-initializing couponAmountString inside the method as you can see. I just had to take out `String` and it's working now!